# Adding text and image in JList in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a GUI in JApplet Form in netbeans which also contains a JList. i just want to know how to add a text and an image before text. i know how to add a text by creating an array and pass it to the constructor of the JList but that was in simple JPanel but in JApplet Form code is disabled (non-editable).I am stuck into it.In Short i want to add my own items in JList in JApplet Form in netbeans. is there any good tutorial or some help. Need an Urgent Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [*Writing a Custom Cell Renderer*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) and the [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) cited.

Comment: +1, yet again the tutorial proves it weight in gold. Hopefully the poster will remember it as a reference.